# Get highest date value of each row in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have got a pandas dataframe that i get by importing a excel sheet. The columns are mainly dates but contain could also be of another data type as for example an id column.  Now I want to get the most recent date of each row and the correlating column name in order to get a list or series of tuples of the kind: id + most recent date. I am pretty new to this and would be thankful for any help. 
Here is some code example.

```
 import pandas as pd   
 import os

 def main():
   #df=importExcel()
   #getLastActions(df)
   df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4], 
                'y':[true,false,true,true],
                'date1':[1996-05-31,2002-01-01,1999-07-17,2019-01-01],
                'date2':[2010-10-11,2000-05-01,1999-12-17,1999-02-02],
                'date3':[1993-09-11,2005-11-11,1997-08-08,2019-04-15] })
    getLastActions(df1)

 def importExcel():
   wk_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
   df = pd.read_excel (wk_dir+'/OPS.xlsx')
   return df

 def getLastActions(df):
   columns = list(df)
   for i in columns:
       #.......
 if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I would like to get sth. like: 
result= [(1,2010-10-11),(2,2005-11-11),(3,1999-12-17),(4,2019-04-15)]

So to say the maximum value of each row but only of the columns that contain dates.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: `result = [x for x in df1.filter(regex='date').max(1).items()]` ...?

Comment: thanks for the reply @ChrisA. This gives me a list of tuples of id and nan's. Are nan's considered as highest value in case they do appear in a row?

Comment: No doesn't sound right.... only if any values are `NaN`

Comment: `NaN` will cause issues, maybe try `fillna` - `list(df1.filter(regex='date').fillna('0').max(1).items())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create index by `id` column, select datetimes column with [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html),get maximum per rows, convert datetimes to strings and last `Series` to list of tuples by [`Series.items`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html) with `list`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4], 
            'y':[True,False,True,True],
           'date1':pd.to_datetime(['1996-05-31','2002-01-01','1999-07-17','2019-01-01']),
           'date2':pd.to_datetime(['2010-10-11','2000-05-01','1999-12-17','1999-02-02']),
           'date3':pd.to_datetime(['1993-09-11','2005-11-11','1997-08-08','2019-04-15'])})
print(df1)
   id      y      date1      date2      date3
0   1   True 1996-05-31 2010-10-11 1993-09-11
1   2  False 2002-01-01 2000-05-01 2005-11-11
2   3   True 1999-07-17 1999-12-17 1997-08-08
3   4   True 2019-01-01 1999-02-02 2019-04-15

a = (list(df1.set_index('id')
             .select_dtypes('datetime')
             .max(axis=1)
             .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
             .items()))
print (a)
[(1, '2010-10-11'), (2, '2005-11-11'), (3, '1999-12-17'), (4, '2019-04-15')]
```

**Details**:

```
print (df1.set_index('id').select_dtypes('datetime'))
        date1      date2      date3
id                                 
1  1996-05-31 2010-10-11 1993-09-11
2  2002-01-01 2000-05-01 2005-11-11
3  1999-07-17 1999-12-17 1997-08-08
4  2019-01-01 1999-02-02 2019-04-15

print (df1.set_index('id').select_dtypes('datetime').max(axis=1))
id
1   2010-10-11
2   2005-11-11
3   1999-12-17
4   2019-04-15
dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (df1.set_index('id').select_dtypes('datetime').max(axis=1).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
id
1    2010-10-11
2    2005-11-11
3    1999-12-17
4    2019-04-15
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I am trying to fix it but somehow i still get some errors with both your solutions. Might be because I import from excel and the column data types are not defined? However for the first solution I get the error: TypeError: cannot convert an object of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to a datetimelike index. Afterwards it says: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: for the second solution i get: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: @Mauritius - What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: @Mauritius - change `.filter(like='date')` to `.filter(regex='date')`, I hope it working now.

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1480 entries, 0 to 1479
Data columns (total 23 columns):
appnum                   1480 non-null int64
wo                       1289 non-null float64
div                      69 non-null float64
filing                   1480 non-null datetime64[ns]
pat requested            1480 non-null datetime64[ns]
wo: isr pub              1289 non-null datetime64[ns]
wo: isr office           1289 non-null object
wo: start regio          1289 non-null datetime64[ns]

Comment: esr/sesr mailed          747 non-null datetime64[ns]
esr/sesr pub             174 non-null datetime64[ns]
time to search report    747 non-null float64
esr reply                1266 non-null datetime64[ns]
ex request               1454 non-null datetime64[ns]
first ex report          453 non-null datetime64[ns]
time to first exam       453 non-null float64
last ex report           434 non-null datetime64[ns]

Comment: last ex reply            363 non-null datetime64[ns]
time since last reply    1304 non-null float64
oral proc                24 non-null datetime64[ns]
deemed withdrawn         20 non-null datetime64[ns]
intent grant             12 non-null datetime64[ns]
refused                  31 non-null datetime64[ns]
notice appeal            10 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](16), float64(5), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 266.0+ KB

Comment: damn i forgot sth.. how would i include another value to the tuple. so i would also have information about which column the highest value comes from? Sorry I hope i am not to annoying. Sth like (1, 2010-10-11, 'date2')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194544/discussion-between-mauritius-and-jezrael).

Comment: @Mauritius - I understand working on it. Btw, what is your pandas version?

Comment: 0.22.0 is the pandas version